# Keep global constants in some files in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I would like to define some global constants in Node.js. After careful study, I guess this is a proper way:

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
    A_LEN: 10,
    B_LEN: 10,
)};
```

But I ran into a problem, can I define a constant using the values that have been defined above, like this:

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
    A_LEN: 10,
    B_LEN: 10,
    C_LEN: A_LEN + B_LEN,
)};
```

How could this be implemented? Or is there any more decent way in Node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define these constants just adding some lines:

```
const A_LEN = 10;
const B_LEN = 10;
const C_LEN = A_LEN + B_LEN;
module.exports = Object.freeze({
    A_LEN,
    B_LEN,
    C_LEN,
)};
```

In case you don't know, these snippets are equivalent:

```
const x = 14;
{ x };     // This is equivalent to
{ x: 14 }; // this
{ x: x };  // or this
```

Comment: It truly works. Is this kind of style commonly used? I mean: { x } is some kind of special tricks or a normal style?

Comment: `{ x }` is the shorthand for `{x: x}`